# MuleSoft Dataweave reduce

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I try to get my head around the  reduce function in Mulesoft Dataweave 2.0.

expected outcome:

```
{
  "dev": "1",
  "test": "2",
  "uat": "3",
  "prod": "4"
}
```

my dataweave code:

```
%dw 2.0
var invar = [
  {"id": "1", "name": "dev"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "test"},
  {"id": "3", "name": "uat"},
  {"id": "4", "name": "prod"}
]
output application/json
---
// invar reduce() ???  requirment: it must be done with reduce function.
```

Thanks

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133645/how-do-you-convert-sql-server-select-into-xml-in-mule-4/60140222#60140222) that I explain `reduce`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to set the accumulator to the correct value when DataWeave can not deduce it automatically:

```
%dw 2.0
var invar = [
  {"id": "1", "name": "dev"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "test"},
  {"id": "3", "name": "uat"},
  {"id": "4", "name": "prod"}
]
output application/json
---
invar reduce ((item, accumulator= {}) -> accumulator ++ {(item.name):item.id})
```

Comment: Thanks Aled, Still can not get my head around this why this works. Because when you do a concatenate it adds strings together. So Dataweave "knows" when the index parameter of the reduce = {}  that the result must be between curly brackets. Right ?

Comment: reduce() operate on arrays, but the concatenate operation ´++´ can operate on arrays, strings, objects and several types of dates combinations. Because I set the accumulator to an object and the second parameter of concatenation is another object, it does an object concatenation as described at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-plusplus#plusplus3

Comment: Exactly, the ++ function is overloaded for different DataWeave types.

Comment: One other thing. DataWeave doesn't exactly "know" what data type the accumulator must be.

When you do not initialize the accumulator, it takes both its data type and its initial value from the first element of the array. When that happens the lambda operates on the second element and the ones after that.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise accumulator to empty object {} and add the formed key value pairs to the accumulator for the required output:

`invar reduce ((item, accumulator = {}) -> accumulator ++ {(item.name): item.id } )`

Answer (score 1):

Reduce works on Array and keep accumulating each array iteration and return once processing is done. In your example, I initialize the accumulator with empty object {}, and in every iteration, I use item.name as the object key and item.id as the value.

```
var invar = [
  {"id": "1", "name": "dev"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "test"},
  {"id": "3", "name": "uat"},
  {"id": "4", "name": "prod"}
]
output application/json
---
invar reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ {
    (item.name) : item.id
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%dw 2.0
var invar = [
  {"id": "1", "name": "dev"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "test"},
  {"id": "3", "name": "uat"},
  {"id": "4", "name": "prod"}
]
output application/json
---
invar reduce ((item, acc = {}) -> acc ++ {(item.name) : item.id})
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted one?