# Mule 4: Dataweave2.0 : how to pass path as property to fetch data

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Can dw2.0 read path from yaml property file?

for example say input is

```
{
  "head": {
    "country": "US",
    "body": {
      "USStates": {
        "stateName": "California",
        "stateCode": "CL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have to fetch stateCode value from above request. Based on country name, the path changes every time (like ChinaStates,IndiaStates etc)

So is there a way to pass input path as parameter to Data weave? We are using yaml properties.
I tried below code, its resulting in null value

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
if(p("countryName." ++ (payload.head.country as String)) != null)
          payload.p("countryName." ++ (payload.head.country))
else "not in scope"
```

and in yaml it declared as below

```
countryName:
  US : head.body.USStates.stateCode
  INDIA : head.body.IndiaStates.stateCode
```

I even tried passing path from payload then it was taking as string.
please suggest

Comment: What is the issue you are having exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

I did use a variable for the path instead of reading it from the YAML config for the sake of simplicity.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = {
  "head": {
    "country": "US",
    "body": {
      "USStates": {
        "stateName": "California",
        "stateCode": "CL"
      }
    }
  }
}

var path = "head.body.USStates.stateCode"

---
path splitBy /\./ reduce (e,acc=data) -> acc[e]
```

Edit: if you need an explanation, just ask and I 'll re-edit later on with all the details.  No time right now :).

Edit1: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133645/how-do-you-convert-sql-server-select-into-xml-in-mule-4/60140222#60140222) for an explanation of `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I do need explanation. I understood by splitting we are creating an array of the path. Accumulator is declared as payload. Please explain acc[e] doing in code, i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: `reduce` is an iterator, which takes an array and passes whatever is returned by the current iteration, plus the next item. It goes over each item in the array, in this case `['head', 'body', 'USStates', 'stateCode']`. The accumulator is what gets returned by the function, and passed into the next iteration of the function. So as you iterate through the parts of the path, the accumulator is being returned with that specific part of the object. So on the first iteration, you get back `{ "country": ..., "body": ...`. Then on the next `{ "USStates": ...`, so on and so forth. @PrudhviB

Answer (score 2):

Is the `stateName` and `stateCode` piece consistent? If so you could do something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    country: payload.head.country,
    stateName: payload.head.body[0].stateName,
    stateCode: payload.head.body[0].stateCode
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "country": "US",
  "stateName": "California",
  "stateCode": "CL"
}
```

But yes, you can address it like this:

`payload.head.body[p('countryName.$(payload.head.country)')].stateCode` should also work, though more complicated than necessary.

Edit:

I see based on your answer why this wouldn't necessarily work. George's answer is correct, but I thought I'd throw this in as well since it is a slightly more complete function for doing this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun getField(payload: Any, field: String) = do {
    var path = field splitBy '.' reduce((pathPart, path=[]) ->
        if (pathPart contains '[') do {
            var pieces = pathPart splitBy '['
            ---
            pieces reduce((piece,subPath=path) -> 
                if (piece contains ']') subPath << (piece replace ']' with '') as Number
                else subPath << piece
            )
        }
        else path << pathPart
    )
    ---
    getField(payload, path)
}

fun getField(payload: Any, field: Array) =
    if (sizeOf(log('field',field)) == 1) payload[field[0]]
    else getField(payload[field[0]], field[1 to -1])
```

Using this function you would do:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
getField(payload, p('country.$(payload.head.country)'))
```

This is a get field by path function.

[image: screenshot of dwlang.fun with code]

Comment: Problem is the path might not be consistent. Some times stateCode field might have a different name. Its up to the requesting country. We were asked to check on country name and declare the path. So instead of writing code for all given countries, I want to externalize paths to accommodate any more countries getting added in future without disturbing the code by updating the property file.

Comment: @PrudhviB - George's answer is good; I updated my answer to include a reusable function that I use for a getField by path. I have this packaged up in a reusable dataweave module.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the structure is too complex for the builtin selectors. I don't think you can use the DataWeave single-value selector (the dot '.') inside a dynamic expression in that way. If you leave only the attribute name in the property it will work. I recommend to simplify the data if possible.

Example:

Property countrName.US: "USStates"

and the expression:

```
  payload.head.body[p("countrName.US")].stateCode
```

Otherwise if you absolutely need a path expression see George's answers.