# Is there a way to parameterise json path in dataweave mulesoft filter operation?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a json structure as

```
{"root":{ "dad": {"son":"jesus"}}
```

If i have to like do

```
payload filter ($.root.dad.son == "jesus"),
```

Can I parameterise this whole "$.root.dad.son" json path?

```
var firstHolder="root"
var secondHolder="dad"
I know we can do $.[firstHolder].[secondHolder] and so on..
```

But wanted to know if it is possible to do

```
var jsonPath="$.root.dad.son"
payload filter (jsonPath == "jesus")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mule 4: Dataweave2.0 : how to pass path as property to fetch data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68747875/mule-4-dataweave2-0-how-to-pass-path-as-property-to-fetch-data). You can easily adapt the method from that answer (path is jsonPath and data is the payload).

Comment: Yes, George (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3078986/george) answer using reduce was amazing! Thanks aled!